# GDB: Is function address fixed or dynamic for every program on different hardware platform?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, remote-debugging, gdbserver

If we write a C code like `printf("%p\n", __builtin_return_address(0));` and suppose we get the result `0xabcd` **from customer's platform**. And then, we run the same program with gdb **on our platform**, and we find out that `0xabcd` maps to `sample_function()`, is this same function on customer's platform when he is running that program? Or in other word, is stack address fixed or dynamic for same program but different hardware platform?

Comment: Most modern operating systems implement address-space randomization, as a protection against security exploits. So even on the same hardware platform addresses aren't fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to prevent some attacks, such as buffer overflow, operating systems use Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR). ASLR ensures that each time you run a program, the addresses will be placed randomly on virtual address space.
On Linux, it is enabled by default. You can disable it by running

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

And then, if you want to enable it again, just run

```
echo 2 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

For more information you can check this article [How Effective is ASLR on Linux Systems?](https://securityetalii.es/2013/02/03/how-effective-is-aslr-on-linux-systems/)

On the other hand, ASLR is disabled in gdb by default to ease debugging. You can enable/disable it with these commands

```
set disable-randomization off
set disable-randomization on
```